# How to proxy a starman request to Apache?

Tags: perl, psgi, starman

I use starman for my webapp. Apache web server listens on port 8080.
I want to rewrite some request like `'/request'` to this Apache web-server in starman. I try to find some pm, but I found few examples to help me.

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to do it.  Apache proxying to starman is the much more common case.

Answer (score 1):

[Plack::App::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Plack-App-Proxy/lib/Plack/App/Proxy.pm) lets you proxy to another web server in your app.psgi.  Modified from the synopsis:

```
use Plack::Builder;

# proxy all requests for /request to 127.0.0.1:8080
builder {
    mount "/request" => Plack::App::Proxy->new(remote => "http://127.0.0.1:8080")->to_app;
};
```

Comment: you are right.Perhaps at the beginning, I think in a wrong way. And of course, we can use nginx to solve this problem. anyway,tks~